# Interfacing Rtabmap and Robot_Localization

Tags: slam, navigation, ekf-localization, robot, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working to use robot_localization to take in info from a piksi gps, rp 2d lidar, and UM7 IMU and to give me a good estimate of where I am in space. I want to report this to rtabmap so I can relate this position to the 3d environment of my robot. When I run rtabmap without [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) everying works, however when I run [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) alongside rtabmap the odom frame drifts like crazy. I didn't know if this was an issue that you have seen before or not. Let me know what you need from me!

Here is my Launch file folder: https://github.com/zastrix/ROS-Launch-Files.git

rtabmap Launch file called [robo_loco.launch](https://github.com/zastrix/ROS-Launch-Files/blob/master/robo_loco.launch)
Robot Localization launch file called [rgbd_mapping.launch](https://github.com/zastrix/ROS-Launch-Files/blob/master/rgbd_mapping.launch)

Thanks for all the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225694/interfacing-rtabmap-and-robot_localization/) by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-02-04**:
The "odom frame drifts", do you mean /map->/odom or /odom->/base_link? Also, is it the output of robot_localization that is drifting? An IMU would drift over time (even if not moving), did you try IMU+visual odometry alone with one robot_localization (without the one for map)?

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-02-08**:
The IMU information that we had set up for RL to input was incorrect. Now that we have our launch files fixed rtabmap is working. However the instance of RL that does the tf from map to odom is not performing the transform. Running diagnostics we get /odom/filtered: no events recorded

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-02-09**:
I also re submitted another question for this issue titled Robot_Localization not publishing transform to odom

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-02-09**:
I don't think the second robot_localization node should be used for /map -> /odom transform. This transform is generally published by a node after global localization or correcting the map (after a loop closure for example) at low frequency (e.g., amcl or rtabmap nodes).

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-02-09**:
Does rtabmap provide the transform from map to odom if we only use one instance of RL? The whole reason we are using RL is to have a better representation of where we are in space so if we don't NEED to do the sensor fusion in RL to get this accuracy then that would be great.

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-02-09**:
Another issue has arose as well. When we try to run the scan matching rtabmap crashes and we have no idea why.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-02-09**:
Yes, rtabmap node doesn't require robot_localization. robot_localization would be used to do odometry fusion of multiple sources (IMU, visual odometry, wheel odometry, etc...), giving the filtered odometry topic to rtabmap. With `publish_tf=:true`, rtabmap publishes /map->/odom.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-02-09**:
For the crash, this may be related to this [post](http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/rtabmap-process-error-td1031.html)

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-02-09**:
If we were integrating a swiftnav gps as well as the imu and visual odometry, wouldn't we need to run two instances of RL? We have set the publish_tf param to false and rtabmap is still publishing the transform. RL and rtabmap are fighting each other over this which I think is most of the issue.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-02-09**:
publish_tf to false should disable /map->/odom from rtabmap as in this [code](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/622d15ea6ae09ea5b8da2e7055fd447a1c7017cb/src/CoreWrapper.cpp#L429) (the TF thread is not created). I'll will verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just read [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration), using two [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) instances makes more sense now if you use a GPS.

The problem is that [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) doesn't know there is a GPS going on, it will generate its own /map -> /odom transform, which is the localization correction after a loop closure. This transform is relative to the starting position of the robot.

Without the GPS, a standard setup would be:
[image: image description]

You could disable map optimization from [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) (`<param name="RGBD/OptimizeIterations" type="string" value="0"/>`) to avoid /map -> /odom publishing if the second [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) with GPS is publishing it too. Then use the output of the second [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) as input odometry for rtabmap node. The map will be created using poses including the GPS, so in some way the map will be already optimized (no loop closure detection required). There may be "jumps" in the generated map though when a GPS localization occurs. Note that the following is just an idea (I've never tested a system like that):

[image: image description]

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) on 2017-04-11**:
Has anyone tested this (Rtabmap, Robot_Localization, and GPS) and can say whether it worked? Is the diagram connection marked with "???" actually correct?

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-07-28**:
Dear @matlabbe,
Now that the tf: /map -> /odom is going to be created by robot_localization pkg, then from where the map will be loaded?
where is the map have been stored?? and how it has been created and saved??

and Does rtabmap in this situation run in localization mode? yes? I mean we just need to launch rtabmap in localization mode, and deletd the parameter related to the database (~/.ros/database.db), am i I right?

Thanks

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-07-30**:
and also what would happen if GPS for sometime not being available! because we have also disabled publishing tf in rtabmap. so what would happen in that case???

Kind Regards

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-08-05**:
Hi everyone,
Does anyone have the tf tree of implementation of rtabmap with two instances of Robot_localization pkg?

**Comment by [JadTaw](https://answers.ros.org/users/88558/jadtaw/) on 2021-12-22**:
The visual odometry source mentioned. Can this also be the rgbd_odometry node in rtabmap_ros? So the total setup includes both the rgbd_odometry and the rtabmap nodes? Would this be redundant, since both are using the same RGBD source for their computations?